# leaflet map and controllers doesn't show

Tags: javascript, html

> this is my INDEX.html here - since this is my first time using this kind of library (leaflet), I don't know how to call it in my index.

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/leaflet/leaflet.css" />
        <script src="scripts/leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
        <div
          id="map"
          style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #888888; margin: 0"
        ></div>
    
        <script type="text/Javascript">
                //declare map object
                var map = L.map('map', {
              center: [51.505, -0.09],
              zoom: 13
          });
                //reference titles
                 L.tileLayer('maps/map_smartue/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
                // markers and popups
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

L.tileLayer('maps/mapping_smartue/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
minZoom:1 ,
maxZoom:4,
continuousWorld: false,
noWrap: true
}).addTo(map);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).